# SQL count new values only with partition by - running count with no duplicates

Tags: sql, presto

Based on table below in Presto I need a column for all new 'rid'. What I managed to do is the same what I can achieve with partition by but it's not exactly what I'm looking for ([db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=196ea2de789e2dcae3f542c2c7e8807c)).

Goal is to have many groupings counts but I think this should describe problem sufficiently.

[image]

I need data truncated by days and column for new users every day as shown at example below. In simple words - if value repeats don't count it. I've tried to find correlation between this and relational division problem but I just stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`row_number()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#row_number) to rank the records of each `rid` by `time`; then you can aggregate and count in only the top record per group.

```
select
    date_trunc(day, t.time) dy,
    count(*) rid_count,
    sum(case when t.rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end) new_rid_count
from (
    select 
        t.*
        row_number() over(partition by t.rid order by t.time) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by date_trunc(day, t.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as two levels of aggregation.  The inner one to get the earliest date.  The outer to aggregate:

```
select first_day, count(*) 
from (select rid, date_trunc('day', min(time))::date as first_day
      from orders o
      group by rid
     ) r
group by 1
```